# Customise the reload of a JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP file in which there are some tab determined by `div`, for example

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Tab1</li>
    <li>Tab2</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    tab 1 here
  </div>
  <div>
    tab 2 here
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I wrote some javascript in tab2 that tell the page to reload (`window.location.reload()`). I need to get the newly reloaded page to place the focus on tab 2, instead of tab 1.

Are there any ways to customize the reload stuff using client side code.

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Comment: As you're using an `<ul>` while talking about a tabset I assume you're already using some Javascript tabset implementation, and these commonly provide the feature you're looking for (have a look at [JQueryUI's tabset](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax), so it might be useful to add what tabset implementation you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you call the page with parameter, that tell which tab get focus while you load the page.

```
eg: window.location.href='something.jsp?tab=tab1';
```

And also instead of

```
window.location.reload();
```

You reload the page with parameter

```
window.location=document.url+"?tab=tab2";
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of reload, change the location to the same page and send a parameter

```
window.location.href = <your page here>?focus=2
```

to get the parameters use something like:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

set the jsp body to call this function onload:

```
<body onload="focus()">

function focus() {
    tab = getUrlVars()["focus"]; //this will give you the number of the tab you shall focus
}
```